# Can I set a Dependent Picklist to an unavailable value by Field Update?

Tags: dependent-picklist

I don't want a user to manually set the Status to "Complete". I want to force them to press the Approve button - and let a Field Update in the Approval Process set it.

But I want the user to be able to manually set Status to other values, such as "Working - Almost Done".

So, I don't want a value such as "Complete" to ever be available in the picklist. So I'm making the picklist a dependent picklist in which the logic only allows values such as "Working - Almost Done" available to be manually chosen at all times.

My question : Will that cause an error when the Field Update in the Approval Process tries to set the value to "Complete" when "Complete" is not available due to dependent picklist settings ?

...or is there a better method than this ? It seems like a somewhat klunky solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the value in dependent picklist from workflow will not cause any issues as long as picklist value is defined in the picklist (otherwise you could receive error if `Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set` is chosen).

Ideally you can create a separate recordtype and page layout and assign the dependent values including `Complete` and during field update you will also update recordtype.